# ASP.NET WebApi base Uri of the application from non-Request worker thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an **ASP.NET WebApi** application running in IIS. From a **non-Request background worker** thread I need to find out the **base Uri of the application** (e.g., https://machineName:port/applicationName/).

The usual suggestions do not work since the Request object is null in the case of a worker thread that was created in the Application_Start() method.

**Update:** I am adding the port to the environment-specific web.config file which gets merged at deployment time (as suggested by @Kenneth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath` property.

It's located in the `System.Web.Hosting`-namespace of the System.Web assembly

This is the MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, that only provides /applicationName/ but not the port number (in case the application is using a non-default port). Is there a way to get the port number separately to reconstruct the entire application Uri?

Comment: afaik that's not possible. There are a few workarounds, which require you to wait until the first request has come in and then capture the info: http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/ However, you should probably rethink why you need this. I'd say you can probably keep that info inside your web.config and change it (preferably automated) when you deploy

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the same solution as @Kenneth.

Otherwise, I guess you could grab the value on App Start and capture it in memory for later usage.